# C# - Problem with Process.Start statement

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am having problems when executing an event in C# using Process.Start. The statement below only outputs half of the command:

```
private void AddTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("schtasks.exe", string.Format(@"/Create /SC DAILY /TN", "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"", string.Format(@"/TR C:\Program Files\test\scanner.exe C:\", "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"")));
}
```

For some reason it cuts of at "/TN" e.g.

"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe" /Create /SC DAILY /TN

Comment: You might also want to check out the (good) [answers to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402969/c-using-scheduled-tasks-with-process-start) that show you how to do it (in a better way) using `ProcessStartInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason it cuts of at "/TN"

Correct. In

```
 string.Format(@"/Create /SC DAILY /TN", "other strings");
```

The first string is seen as the format string, the rest are arguments, unused in this case.
Without `{0}` place holders you don't need `String.Format()`, simply use

```
 Process.Start("schtasks.exe", @"/Create /SC DAILY /TN" + "\"" + ...
```

That doesn't exclude the possibility of a syntax error in your commandline arguments.

Change it to :

```
string args =  @"/Create /SC DAILY /TN" + "\"" + ...
Process.Start("schtasks.exe", args);
```

And then you can inspect `args` in the debugger and maybe post here.

Comment: @Thanks, glad someone gets the situation :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised an exception isn't being thrown. You format string is `@"/Create /SC Daily /TN"`. It doesn't have any place holders (i.e. `{0}`), so it has no where to put the values passed in for all the other parameters of `string.Format()`.

If you can post an example of what the output should look like (it's hard to tell from your code example), then either I, or someone else, should be able to give you the proper `string.Format()` you need to use.

Comment: You don't need to use `string.Format()` you can use straight string concatenation, but `string.Format()` generally makes code much more readable. However, if you are OK with hard-coding paths, then try: @"/Create /SC DAILY /TN Scan /TR ""C:\Program Files\test\scanner.exe 'C:\"""